# Web API 2 OWIN Bearer token authentication/ How do I Change /Token path

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin, single-page-application

I'm writing a SPA application with OWIN authentication. Initially my app was built to run as the default app in IIS and so my Authorization options looked like this (TokenEndpointPath = "/Token")

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                //Exposes Token endpoint
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                //Use ApplicationOAuthProvider in order to authenticate
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/MyApp/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14), //Token expiration => The user will remain authenticated for 14 days
                AllowInsecureHttp = true                
            };
```

However, I'm needing to move this so that it's no longer the default app but a child application within the default IIS app all of my api calls will go from this path:

```
http://localhost:22657/
```

to:

```
http://localhost:22657/MyApp
```

So, the /Token path is no longer reachable. So, I've altered my TokenEndpointPath to be:

```
TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/MyApp/Token"),
```

However, when I authenticate my browser successfully makes the call, however, the response from the server is the HTML from my Index.cshtml file. I don't know how to diagnose why WebApi is processing the request that way (it's clearly not being processed by OWIN. When I set a breakpoint on my GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method the breakpoint isn't hit ).

None of my WebApi routes are configured with "Token" in it.

1) Does anyone know what is going on with the endpoint and why it's returning html rather than the bearer token or how I should go about troubleshooting it?

Update:

I guess it must be related to the following default route which specifies the Index. This is causing requests to /MyApp/Token to be routed to Home/Index.  Is there something else I could use in place of "{*url}" to prevent this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{*url}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

MVC was intercepting the call to the WebApi /MyApp/Token endpoint. In attempting to have MVC ignore this route I had added the second line below:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{Token}");
```

However, this wasn't working. When I moved the line to ignore "Token" to the top it worked:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{Token}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```